# codeigniter disable automatic update updated_at filed

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->db->update(XXXX)
```

Execute this command will auto update the database filed which called updated_at

How can I do? I do not want to automatic update the updated_at filed

Comment: change `extra` datatype correspond with `updated_at` to `null` in your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally,I find some setting in my database.
this filed has been set as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  whitch can result in  automatic update itself.

Answer (score 0):

When create new table use default timestamp for updated_at field.